# Css3pie Round Corners not working in IE8 with :after

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css3pie

my round corners seems to not work in ie8 but works in ie7 if i use the :after element:

```
.readmore:after {
width:17px;
height:17px;
margin-left:5px;
display:inline-block;

font-family: 'bridge';
color:#e21e36;
content:'E';
text-align:center;
line-height:19px;
font-size:15px;

border: 1px solid #fff;

-webkit-border-radius: 9px;
   -moz-border-radius: 9px;
        border-radius: 9px;
          behavior: url('http://fileserver/bridge/PIE.htc');
}
```

How can i enable this in ie8?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the pie syntax.

```
-pie-border-radius: 9px;
```

try loading pie relative to your CSS documents location, i.e.

```
behavior: url(/your/path/theme/inc/PIE.htc);
```

**Edit**:

The PIE.htc requests should respond with the mime type "text/x-component" - or IE won't touch the behaviour. Maybe your issue is with Serving the correct Content-Type, please see this for more info:

http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

Comment: thanks it still shows no round borders, but in IE7 works perfectly

Comment: Are you sure - are you clearing cache? Maybe it's your pie location then. See my edit.

Comment: Yeah i have cleared and tried everything. Thanks for the help. I also use a absolute path directly to the file which works in ie7.

Comment: Yes, but the path is relative to the HTML file being viewed, not the CSS file it is called from.

Comment: Yes, but we don't know that PIE will respond to the type of path he's giving it do we?